# Workaround to static member inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, static

I'm actually working on a project in which I need a bunch of objects (classes if you prefer, rather than instances) to implement a same behavior. Basically, each "class" would need to provide a way of manipulating an array containing each instance of it.

Coding something like this bothers me :

```
function A() { ... }
A.instances = [];
A.someStaticMethod = function () {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < A.instances ; i++) {
        A.instances[i].doSomething();
    }
}
A.prototype.doSomething = function () { ... }

function B() { ... }
B.instances = [];
B.someStaticMethod = function () {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < B.instances ; i++) {
        B.instances[i].doSomething();
    }
}
B.prototype.doSomething = function () { ... }
```

I just don't like having some kind of copied/pasted-like code. Coming from class languages, I naturally thought all I had to do was to create a third class which'd implement those static member/method and have my other classes to inherit from it.
Little did I know, you can't inherit static members.

I'm willing to learn how javascript works, so I was wondering if there is any way to get the wanted behavior without having to duplicate code each time.

Comment: How are static methods inherited in other languages?

Comment: They're not, I guess. But still, my problem is linked to the static property anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a function to enhance your objects using a sort of *mixin* function.

```
function enhanceStatic(type) {
    type.instances = [];
    type.someStaticMethod = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < type.instances.length; i++) {
            type.instances[i].doSomething();
        }
    };
}

function A(msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}
enhanceStatic(A);
A.prototype.doSomething = function () {
    console.log("A: " + +this.msg);
}

function B(msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}
enhanceStatic(B);
B.prototype.doSomething = function () {
    console.log("B: " + +this.msg);
}

A.instances = [new A(1), new A(2)];
B.instances = [new B(1), new B(2), new B(3)];
A.someStaticMethod();
B.someStaticMethod();
```

Output:

```
A: 1
A: 2
B: 1
B: 2
B: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to implement class like behaviour in javascript. A framework to mention is ExtJs (and also prototype), which has a clear and simple syntax and supports static methods. Annoyed by huge code base and the license (GPL, commercial) which made it impossible to write small budget projects with the same code i wrote a class manager that stands under the MIT License called Esf-Core for the core class loader functionality (https://npmjs.org/package/esf-core) that is similar to ExtJS coding style. Here is an example how to use it:

```
Esf.define('A', {
    a: null,

    constructor: function (a) {
        // Save var
        this.a = a;

        // Heyho
        console.log('A');
    },
    foo: function (b) {
        console.log('foo - ' + b);
    }
});

Esf.define('B', {
    b: null,

    constructor: function (a, b) {
        // Call super constructor
        this.callParent(a);

        // Save var
        this.b = b;

        // Heyho
        console.log('B');
    },
    foo: function () {
        this.callParent('bar');
    }
}, {
    extend: 'A'
});

// Use
var b = new B(1, 2);

// or
var b = Esf.create('B', 1, 2);

/*
 * Output:
 * A
 * B
 * foo - bar
 */
b.foo();
```

Static methods are not yet implemented but will (you can do on your own if you'd like, its only a piece of code) in the near future and also a class loader for dynamic loading with dependencies. The main framework which is still in progress will also bring dependency injection and models stores etc. based on backbone.

There are multiple other ways to do so in a even more lightweight way if you see here: [javascript inheritance framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408065/javascript-inheritance-framework/13940803) (End of the thread)

Here is the ExtJS way for static methods:

```
Ext.define('Computer', {
     statics: {
         factory: function() {
             // This refers to the class not the object in static context
             return this.factory;
         }
     },

     factory: 'Unknown',
});

Ext.define('PC', {
     extends: 'Computer',

     factory: 'Dell',
});

// Dell
console.log(PC.factory());
```

The code should work but i didn't try :-)

Comment: That's so complicated for something so simple... What a disappointment. I guess I'll have to go with this if there's nothing better. Thanks !